# Airflow- failing a task which returns no data?

Tags: airflow

What would the best way be to fail a task which is the result of a BCP query (command line query for MS SQL server I am connecting to)?

I am downloading data from multiple tables every 30 minutes. If the data doesn't exist, the BCP command is still creating a file (0 size). This makes it seem like the task was always successful, but in reality it means that there is missing data on a replication server another team is maintaining.

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table WHERE row_date = '2016-05-28' AND interval = 0" queryout /home/var/filename.csv -t, -c -S server_ip -U user -P password
```

The row_date and interval would be tied to the execution date in Airflow. I would like for airflow to show a failed task instance if the query returned no data though. Any suggestions?

- Check for file size as part of the task?
- Create an upstream task which reads the first couple of rows and tells Airflow whether the query was valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would use your first suggestion and check for the file size as part of the task.

If it is not possible to do this in the same task as the query, create a new one with that specific purpose with an upstream dependency. In the cases that the file is empty just trigger an exception in the task.